# TDengine timestamp resolution options

Tags: database, timestamp, tdengine

According to TDengine official documentation description:

```
Default time precision of TDengine is millisecond, you can change it to microseocnd by setting parameter enableMicrosecond.
```

I checked in the example configuration file under packaging/cfg/taos.cfg, there's no such parameter to set so wondering if the description is deprecated. So does anyone know the right way to set different timestamp resolutions and what options does TDengine support?(seconds, nanoseconds?)

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation is not updated yet. In TDengine database, you can use precision to control the timestamp resolution.
For example

```sql
taos> create database db1 precision 'ms';
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.002368s)

taos> create database db2 precision 'us';
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.002327s)

taos> create database db3 precision 'ns';
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.002664s)

taos> show databases;
              name              |      created_time       |   ntables   |   vgroups   | replica | quorum |  days  |           keep           |  cache(MB)  |   blocks    |   minrows   |   maxrows   | wallevel |    fsync    | comp | cachelast | precision | update |   status   |
====================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 db2                            | 2021-11-16 16:20:57.721 |           0 |           0 |       1 |      1 |     10 | 3650                     |          16 |           6 |         100 |        4096 |        1 |        3000 |    2 |         0 | us        |      0 | ready      |
 db1                            | 2021-11-16 16:20:50.387 |           0 |           0 |       1 |      1 |     10 | 3650                     |          16 |           6 |         100 |        4096 |        1 |        3000 |    2 |         0 | ms        |      0 | ready      |
 db3                            | 2021-11-16 16:21:04.788 |           0 |           0 |       1 |      1 |     10 | 3650                     |          16 |           6 |         100 |        4096 |        1 |        3000 |    2 |         0 | ns        |      0 | ready      |
Query OK, 3 row(s) in set (0.001752s)
```